# Почему slash ("/") в начале пути к файлу где-то нужен, а где-то не нужен?

Tags: java, path

Здравствуйте.
Есть примеры приложений на Java, там прописываются пути к картинкам так

```
construirDatabase.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/logo_pequeño.png")));
```

У меня нет ошибки только если "косую черту" убрать. Почему это?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Имя ресурса может быть абсолютным и относительным. Абсолютное имя начинается с символа `/`. В этом случае ресурс ищется относительно корня classpath. Т.е. берутся все пути и jar-файлы, входящие в classpath, и ресурс ищется относительно совокупности этих точек. Если же имя относительное – к нему в начало приписывается путь, полученный из пакета текущего класса, и далее поиск ведется как в случае абсолютного имени.

Для примера, пусть у нас задан classpath `c:\projects\someproject\classes;c:\libs\somelib.jar`. Код примера находится в классе `com.example.SomeClass`.

Поиск ресурса по **абсолютному имени** `getClass().getResource("/images/logo.png")` происходит следующим образом:

К пути из classpath `c:\projects\someproject\classes` приписывается имя ресурса `/images/logo.png`, в результате чего ищется файл `c:\projects\someproject\classes\images\logo.png`. Если файл найден – поиск прекращается. Если нет, то в jar-файле `c:\libs\somelib.jar` ищется файл `/images/logo.png`, причем поиск ведется от корня jar-файла.

Поиск ресурса по **относительному имени** `getClass().getResource("res/data.txt")` происходит следующим образом:

К пути из classpath `c:\projects\someproject\classes` приписывается текущий пакет класса, где находится код (`/com/example`) и далее имя ресурса `res/data.txt`, в результате чего ищется файл `c:\projects\someproject\classes\com\example\res\data.txt`. Если файл найден – поиск прекращается. Иначе:
В jar-файле `c:\libs\somelib.jar` ищется файл `/com/example/res/data.txt`, поиск ведется от корня jar-файла.