# Чем отличается FileInputStream от InputStream?

Tags: java, io, properties

В данном случае мне надо достать значения из файла *.properties*.
Я могу использовать для этого FileInputStream:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties");
```

А могу обычный InputStream:

```
 InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/initialData.properties");
```

В чем между ними разница?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FileInputStream` - это поток ввода из файла, а `InputStream` - это просто поток ввода, откуда угодно. Но в вашем примере разница не в уровне абстракции потоков, а в способе доступа к ресурсам. В случае использования `FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties")` вы сможете читать файл только в том случае, если в рабочем каталоге вашего приложения обязательно есть каталог `src` с соответствующими подкаталогами, содержащими необходимый файл. Что перестанет быть истинной после упаковки приложения в jar-файл. По крайней мере без дополнительных манипуляций с вашей стороны. Использование же `getResourceAsStream` позволит получить данные как из файла в каталоге, так и из jar-файла. Только путь придётся поменять с `src/main/resources/initialData.properties` на просто `initialData.properties`. Подробнее об именовании ресурсов можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765256/204271).